# IOS9 WKWebView html5 video no playback button

Tags: ios, html5-video, ios9, wkwebview

I'm using WKWebView to display html5 video element. When view is loaded initially there is play button (big round button).  If you press it built-in video fullscreen  controller is displayed and video starts playing.

While video is playing press "Done" button:
1. fullscreen controller collapses and I see my webview
2. but **there is no play button anymore** (so I can't start playing video again)

If you first pause video and that press "Done", or watch video to the end and then press "Done" everything is fine.

Works on IOS8 without issues.

Is it IOS9 bug, or I have something configured wrong?
What workarounds are possible?

Here is html that is loaded into webview:

```
@"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name=""viewport"" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"">
    <style>
        html, body {{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #000;
        }}
        video {{
            background-color: #000;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            max-height: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<video poster=""{0}""><source src=""{1}"" /></video>
</body>
</html>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was missed controls attribute.

From Apple documentation:

> The HTML5  and  tags make it simple to add media to your website. Just include the `<audio>` or `<video>` element, use the src attribute to identify the media source, and include the controls attribute.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Introduction/Introduction.html